# python slicing [:-N] [:-N+1]

Tags: python, indexing, time-series, slice, numpy-slicing

I been trying to code the following line but I get the message that operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (30,)
x has a length of 32

- `x[:-N+1]` I want to access all elements except the last two
- `x[N:-N]`  I want to access all elements except the first one and the last one
- `x[N+1:]`  I want to access all elements except the first

```
y = x[:-N+1] - 2 * x[N:-N] + x[N+1:]
```

How should I index x to access those values? I'm new to python so any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Slice except the last two: `x[:N-2]`
Except first and last: `x[1:N-1]`
Except first two: `x[2:]`

Python slice can be obtained by:
`x[starting_index:end_index]` {including starting_index element and excluding end_index}

If you don't specify the `starting_index`, it becomes 0 by default.
If you don't specify the `end_index`, it becomes N by default.

Comment: One word of caution: Slicing is that simple only while all numbers (start, end, step) are non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering** the list length might be vary, the python has good apporach to access the items of a list.
Given a `alist=['a','b','something',1,2]`

if you use `alist[1:]`, you will get `['b', 'something', 1, 2]`

if you use `alist[:1]`, you will get `['a','b','something',1]`

if you only use  `alist[1]`, you will only get `a` ,which is the first item of the list.

so, if you use `alist[-1:]`, you will get `2` , which is the first item starts from right.

if you use `alist[:-1]`, you will get `['a','b','something',1]` , which are items start from right except the fist.

In conclusion, the **empty** thing in the **[:]** is what you will get after use slicing.

Comment: _if you only use alist[1], you will only get a ,which is the first item of the list._ **wrong**: [1] returns the `second` item.